# Long runtime while creating virtual environment with conda

Tags: conda

### Problem

I am trying to reproduce the experiment in this [repo](https://github.com/neulab/external-knowledge-codegen). The first step to do so is setting up the virtual environment (i.e. installing dozens of dependencies) and the command looks like

```sh
conda env create -n "tranx" -f config/conda_environment.yml
```

However, the runtime for this command is intolerably long. Specifically, even though most of the required libraries do not take much time to install (include some of several hundred MBs), one of the libraries (which is also several hundred MBs) take hours to install.

I am suspecting this is because the default choice of the server makes the installing process long.

When using `pip`, I could use following to manually specify faster server

```sh
pip install -i <server-url> <package-name>
```

I am wondering whether this is possible when trying to create virtual environment using `conda env create`.

Could any one help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: First thing I'd do is add `conda-forge` to the channels in the YAML (give it priority), and then move all the dependencies out of `pip` section - they are all available through Conda. Then retry creating from the modified YAML.

Comment: Where are the dependencies listed? I can't find anything in the repo.